# Removing tabs and spaces between letters - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Here's what I have so far:

```
      while ((currentChar != '\0') && (i < (length - 1)))
      {

          if (isalnum(*currentChar))
          {
              foundAlphaNum = 1;
          }

          if (*currentChar != ' ' && *currentChar != '\t' && *currentChar !='\n' && foundAlphaNum)
          {
              modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
              i++;
          }
          else if ((*currentChar == ' ' || *currentChar == '\t') && !foundAlphaNum)
          {
              modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
              i++;
          }
          else if(*currentChar == '\n')
           {
             modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
             i++;
             foundAlphaNum = 0;
           }

         currentChar++;

     }

     // add null terminating char (maybe...)
     modifiedString[i] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n", modifiedString);
```

heres my output:

```
 "       HelloLbaldkgabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
 helluhworldzguhmornings

 hhulsuhfhdjfue12345678910morealphabettseee"
```

It's supposed to leave any blank before the first letter appears, which it does on the first line but it removes them on the other lines.

I've tried resetting it back to 0, but it gives me a segmentation fault core dump

Comment: Resetting `foundAlphaNum` to zero when you find a linefeed would be an obvious fix...

Comment: have you checked out the function isspace()  ?

Comment: I'm having trouble resetting 'foundAlphaNum' back to zero. Either I'm getting a segmentation fault core dump or it doesn't do anything for me. Or maybe I'm doing resetting 'foundAlphaNum' entirely wrong.. What do I do?

Comment: I'm sorry but what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You do not reset your `foundAlphaNum` when you reach end of line

you should add one more if-statement

```
else if ( *currentChar == '\n' )
{
  modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
  foundAlphaNum = false;
}
```

you could do something like this

```
char buf[255] = {"  your string bla bla\n  bla bla bla\n  bla bla"};
char* p = buf;
int targetIndex = 0;
char modifiedString[255] = {'\0'};
bool beforeLetter = true;

for (p = buf; *p && targetIndex < sizeof(buf); ++p)
{
  if (*p == '\n')
  {
    beforeLetter = true;
  }
  else if ( isspace(*p) && beforeLetter )
  {
    modifiedString[targetIndex++] = *p; // copy preceding spaces
  }
  else if ( isspace(*p) && !beforeLetter )
  {
    ; // skip spaces after letter is found
  }
  else if ( isalphanum(*p) )
  {
    beforeLetter = false;
    modifiedString[targetIndex++] = *p;
  }
}
 modifiedString[targetIndex++] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
while(//Assuming you are doing it line by line //)
{
    i=0;
    flag = 0;
    while ((currentChar != '\0') && (i<length-1))
    {
       if (isalnum(*currentChar))
       {
          flag = 1;
          modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
          i++;
       }
       else if((*currentChar == ' ' || *currentChar == '\t') && !flag)
       {
          modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
          i++;
       } 
       currentChar ++;
    }
    modifiedString[i] = '\0';
    //print or store the modified string for this line //
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *Why ?* the down Vote or the up Vote ? :D

Comment: @Rizier123 It feels like sometime back.. :) I really don't remember what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your code ignore the leading spaces on each line, you could reset `foundAlphaNum` to zero when a newline is found... but you should do so where the test for `'\n'` will actually happen.  In your revised code, the check for `'\n'` happens in an `else` clause that follows an `if` (two back) that will execute instead if an alphanumeric character has already been found on the line, or an earlier one, since this bug prevents `foundAlphaNum` from being reset.

There's also a mistake in your `while` loop condition, where you're comparing the pointer `currentChar`, instead of the character it points at, to `'\0'` which may be what leads to your segfault.

Fixing these problems (leaving your code mostly as is) might give:

```
/* == fixed loop condition == */
while ((*currentChar != 0) && (i < (length -1)))
{
    if (isalnum(*currentChar))
    {
        foundAlphaNum = 1;
    }

    /* == moved '\n' test (now checked first) == */
    if (*currentChar == '\n')
    {
        modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
        i++;
        foundAlphaNum = 0;
    }
    else if (*currentChar != ' ' && *currentChar != '\t' && foundAlphaNum)
    {
        modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
        i++;
    }
    else if ((*currentChar == ' ' || *currentChar == '\t') && !foundAlphaNum)
    {
        modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
        i++;
    }

    currentChar++;

}

// add null terminating char (maybe...)
modifiedString[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", modifiedString);
```

However, there's still plenty of room to clean things up.  For example:

```
while ((*currentChar != 0) && (i < length - 1))
{
    if (isalnum(*currentChar))
        foundAlphaNum = 1;

    switch (*currentChar) {
      case '\n':
        foundAlphaNum = 0;
      case ' ':
      case '\t':
        if (foundAlphaNum)
            break;
      default:
        modifiedString[i++] = *currentChar;
    }

    currentChar++;
}
modifiedString[i] = '\0';
puts(modifiedString);
```

In the above, the `if` sets `foundAlphaNum` if an alphanumeric character is found.  Then the `switch`, making use of case fall-through, clears `foundAlphaNum` if a newline is found, then adds the character to the new string unless it was a space or tab and `foundAlphaNum` is set.  Then `currentChar` is incremented, the terminating nul is added, and the string is printed.

Note also that your code (and the alternative above) only strips spaces and horizontal tabs, and only does so after an *alphanumeric* character is found on the line (as opposed to any non-space character, like punctuation).  If that's not what you want, you may want to replace `isalnum()` with a check that `*currentChar` is not a space or a tab instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
i=0;
flag = 0;
while ((currentChar != '\0') && (i<length-1))
{
   if (isalnum(*currentChar))
   {
      flag = 1;
      modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
      i++;
   }
   else if((*currentChar == ' ' || *currentChar == '\t') && !flag)
   {
      modifiedString[i] = *currentChar;
      i++;
   }
   else if(*currentChar == '\n')
   {
       flag = 0 ;
   } 
   currentChar ++;
}
modifiedString[i] = '\0';
//print or store the modified string for this line //
```

i think this would work... try this..